# SUMPRODUCT and missing values in a column filled with text

Tags: excel

Really hoping you can help me with this. I'm attempt to provide a very general formula to deal with the following problem:

I have a piece of software which provides individuals the ability to assess the entered work activity for a given month. This information is automatically spat out into a CSV file. In column E of the file (It will always be column E) time is represented in the following format:

```
0 hrs  10 mins

1 hrs  59 mins

0 hrs  10 mins
```

Given the number of events recorded, an individual will have 10 lines, 100 lines, or even 1000 lines of activity in this format.

I want to provide them with a formula that they can paste into a single cell which will extract the number of hours they have worked. I have developed the following:

```
SUMPRODUCT((MID(E12:E225,1,1))+(MID(E12:E225,8,2)/60))
```

This gives me almost what i need. However, whenever there is a cell with a missing value, it displays the #Value! error. Many of the internet blogs provide the option to multiply by or add something like this --`(E12:E225<>"")` (same problem with `ISNUMBER`). However, this assesses the value in the cell not the value of the product of the formula above. Ideally, I would like to have a formula which spans the entire E:E column so they don't have to highlight the required cells.

Best i can come up with is a two step solution:

```
L12=SUMPRODUCT((MID(E12,1,1))+(MID(E12,8,2)/60)) (for each cell)

=SUMPRODUCT((L1:L225),--(L1:L225<>""))
```

A few more caveats:

1. Some use Excel 2003, others Excel 2010
2. Spreadsheet literacy is poor (poorer than me)
3. Ideally it needs to be in one equation, otherwise i stand to lose alot of people.

All ideas welcome!

Comment: Will the digit before “ hrs” **always** be `0` or `1`, or could it be more than `9`? What about the digits before “ mins”, could they be < 10?

Comment: Looking at the data, no activity lasts longer than 10 hours. Some are shorter than 10 minutes but are picked up in the current syntax due to changes in formatting by the program. Just to clarify: Minutes are designated as '01' in the case of them being less than 10 minutes

Answer (score 0):

I think this meets your requirements. It's an [array formula](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx) entered with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>enter</kbd>:

```
=SUM(IF(E12:E225="",0,(LEFT(E12:E225,1)*1)+(MID(E12:E225,8,2)/60)))
```